# Update all Sagemaker Jupyter Notebooks with latest git repository changes

Tags: git, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

I have multiple Sagemaker notebooks created for a training class. I need to make a change in the notebooks before the new class starts. So far, the only way I see to do this is to update the repository with changes and then go into each notebook instance individually and do a git pull to update the changes. Is there a way to do this for all notebooks associated with that repository at once?

Comment: The best workaround I have come up with so far is to add !git fetch origin and
!git reset --hard origin/your_branch as the first code cell in the notebook. Where your_branch is the git repository branch for the Sagemaker git repo. Then after running that and waiting a couple minutes you get choice to reload from disk, choose reload and then it updates the current notebook with latest changes in the repo. If you created the notebook with that cell already there, then each user just has to run that cell to update to latest code changes in the repo.

Comment: This is basically same as going to each notebook instance, opening a terminal, and then doing same git commands  but a little easier and less time consuming and it can be built in. Running the cell once in any notebook updates all the files and notebooks in the sagemaker repo. If you try to open another notebook that has changed, it will prompt you to reload from disk. It can take over 2 minutes for the prompt to reload.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a way around git pulling the changes into each instance individually, but to make it easier (both now and in the future) you could consider use a [Lifecycle Configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/notebook-lifecycle-config.html).

The procedure would look something like this:

1. Create a lifecycle config. On notebook start it should run a shell script to pull from your repository
2. Write and run a script to add the lifecycle config to each notebook. Something like:

```
import boto3
import time

lifecycle_config_name='YOUR_CONFIG_NAME'
sagemaker = boto3.client('sagemaker', region_name='us-west-2')
notebook_names = list(map(lambda x: x['NotebookInstanceName'], sagemaker.list_notebook_instances()['NotebookInstances']))


def stop_notebook(notebook_name):
    print(f'Stopping {notebook_name}')
    sagemaker.stop_notebook_instance(NotebookInstanceName=notebook_name)
    while True:
        if sagemaker.describe_notebook_instance(NotebookInstanceName=notebook_name)['NotebookInstanceStatus'] == 'Stopped':
            break
        else:
            time.sleep(5)

def update_notebook(notebook_name):
    print(f'Updating {notebook_name}')
    sagemaker.update_notebook_instance(NotebookInstanceName=notebook_name, LifecycleConfigName=lifecycle_config_name)
    while True:
        if sagemaker.describe_notebook_instance(NotebookInstanceName=notebook_name)['NotebookInstanceStatus'] != 'Updating':
            break
        else:
            time.sleep(5)

for notebook_name in notebook_names:
    if sagemaker.describe_notebook_instance(NotebookInstanceName=notebook_name)['NotebookInstanceStatus'] == 'Pending':
        stop_notebook(notebook_name)
    update_notebook(notebook_name)
    sagemaker.start_notebook_instance(NotebookInstanceName=notebook_name)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out Lifecycle, I may use that down the road but I want to control when I sync to the repo. Lifecycle can either work at notebook creation only or else everytime. I need this after notebook creation and I don't want it to sync to the repo everytime you start the notebook.